# Invalid signature when signing Coinbase request, why?

Tags: go, coinbase-api

According to [Coinbase pro API docs](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#signing-a-message):

> The CB-ACCESS-SIGN header is generated by creating a sha256 HMAC using the base64-decoded secret key on the prehash string timestamp +
> method + requestPath + body (where + represents string concatenation)
> and base64-encode the output. The timestamp value is the same as the
> CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP header.
>
> The body is the request body string or omitted if there is no request
> body (typically for GET requests).
>
> The method should be UPPER CASE.

I borrowed a signing function from a better programmer and feed it something like this:

```
1619383731POST/reports{{"end_date":"2021-01-02T11:59:59Z","start_date":"2020-01-01T00:00:00Z","type":"account"}}
```

But keep getting invalid signature from Coinbase.

Signing function for reference:

```
// sign
func (e *exchange) sign(msg string) string {
    key, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(e.http.secret)
    if e.checkErr(err) {
        return "bad_sig"
    }
    signature := hmac.New(sha256.New, key)
    _, err = signature.Write([]byte(msg))
    if e.checkErr(err) {
        return "bad_sig"
    }
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(signature.Sum(nil))
}
```

Where am I screwing up?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out using `req.Body` directly is the culprit. Why I don't know and something I need to find out, but reading into a `[]byte` and then casting to a string solves part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the go-coinbase github repo implementing this as:
https://github.com/preichenberger/go-coinbasepro/blob/master/client.go

```
h := make(map[string]string)
    h["CB-ACCESS-KEY"] = c.Key
    h["CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE"] = c.Passphrase
    h["CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP"] = timestamp

    message := fmt.Sprintf(
        "%s%s%s%s",
        timestamp,
        method,
        url,
        data,
    )

    sig, err := generateSig(message, c.Secret)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    h["CB-ACCESS-SIGN"] = sig
    return h, nil
```

Comment: Yes, that's actually where I borrowed the sign function from.

Comment: msg := fmt.Sprintf( "%s%s%s%s", timestamp, e.req.Method, e.req.URL.Path, e.req.Body, ) -- generates what Coinbase asks for, so I don't know why the signature's being rejected.